# eye vision problem

Tags: trigonometry

Imagine that the smallest letter that ken can read on the Snellen Eye chart is 3 inches tall. What is Ken's vision, using 20/XX notation?

I have a question about eye vision, but I have no idea how can i start?

am i finding the XX?
and is XX represent Ken vision? or a normal people vision?

what I am thinking is

[image]

it this what the problem want?

it is confusing me right now X~X

Answer (score 3):

The Snellen acuity tests measures visual acuity normalized at a distance of 20 feet.

So someone with 20/40 vision sees at 20 feet the level of detail that a person with 20/20 vision sees at 40 feet.

So you simply need to translate this into ratios.

If, at 20 feet, a person with normal vision can make out a Snellen glyph $n$ inches tall, then a person with 20/40 vision requires the same glyph to be $2n$ inches tall. Alternatively, the person with 20/40 vision needs to be 10 feet away to see the $n$ inch Snellen glyph.

In other words, the Snellen denominator is linear.

---

Vision testing is done at standardized lengths, and we change the size of the glyphs.

There is a baseline accuracy typically used to assess visual acuity (usually like 80% of a "line").

Assume Alice has 20/20 vision, and she can read 80% of the glyphs that are 3" high from 20 feet.

If Bob can read 80% of the glyphs that are 4" high at 20 feet, but less than 80% of the glyphs that are 3" high, then his minimum visual angle for glyph discrimination is 4" divided by 20'. This means that his Snellen denominator is 33% higher than Alice's, so he has 20/(4/3*20) vision, or approximately, 20/27 vision.

Comment: sorry, i am kind of confuse from what you say X~X,so in my problem, is it looking for the XX? and is my diagram correct?

Comment: Your diagram is correct, *sort of*. When I say X, I mean the snellen denominator. So if I'm 20/300, my X is 300.